# What happens to a Thread that fails to acquire a Semaphore?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

What happens when a thread cannot acquire a Semaphore (due to lack of permit). Will it be moved to the wait state?

EDIT:Will the thread start resume the previous execution sequence, when the semaphore becomes available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **What happens when a thread cannot acquire a Semaphore (due to lack of permit). Will it be moved to the wait state?**

Yes. If you're talking about [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (and [the `aquire` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28%29) this is what happens:

> Acquires a permit from this semaphore, blocking until one is available, or the thread is interrupted.
>
> [...]
>
> If no permit is available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of two things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the release() method for this semaphore and the current thread is next to be assigned a permit; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread.

[`tryAquire`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire%28%29) will however, as the name suggests, only try to aquire the lock, and instead of blocking return false if it has no permit.

> **Will the thread start resume the previous execution sequence, when the semaphore becomes available.**

Yes. If another thread calls `release` this thread may return from `acquire` and continue it's execution.

Comment: So it is moved to the BLOCKED state, like what happens when a thread fails to aquire a monitor lock. "wait state" in the question is probably not the right word?